# R - Counting the number of a specific value in bins

Tags: r

I have a data frame (df) like below:

```
Value <- c(1,1,0,2,1,3,4,0,0,1,2,0,3,0,4,5,2,3,0,6)
Sl <- c(1:20)
df <- data.frame(Sl,Value)    

> df
   Sl Value
1   1     1
2   2     1
3   3     0
4   4     2
5   5     1
6   6     3
7   7     4
8   8     0
9   9     0
10 10     1
11 11     2
12 12     0
13 13     3
14 14     0
15 15     4
16 16     5
17 17     2
18 18     3
19 19     0
20 20     6
```

I would like to create 4 bins out of `df` and count the occurrences of `Value=0` grouped by `Sl` values in a separate data frame like below:

```
Bin Count
1   1
2   2
3   2
4   1
```

I was trying to use `table` and `cut` to create the desire data frame but its not clear how I'll specify `df$Value` and the logic to find the `0`s here

```
df.4.cut <- as.data.frame(table(cut(df$Sl, breaks=seq(1,20, by=5))))
```

Comment: Your sample input and output don't match up.  Can you clean up your question?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've updated the question

Comment: @mts could you kindly show how to use tapply with cut?

Comment: Table would need two arguments : `table(cut(df$Sl,4),df$Value)` ; access the count of 0 with : `table(cut(df$Sl,4),df$Value)[,"0"]`

Comment: The solution using `table` is also helpful. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using your `df`

```
tapply(df$Value, cut(df$Sl, 4), function(x) sum(x==0))
```

gives

```
> tapply(df$Value, cut(df$Sl, 4), function(x) sum(x==0))
(0.981,5.75]  (5.75,10.5]  (10.5,15.2]    (15.2,20] 
           1            2            2            1
```

In `cut` you can specify the number of breaks or the breaks itself if you prefer and the logic is in the function definition in `tapply`

Comment: That works !! I just modify the `cut` as 
tapply(df$Value, cut(df$Sl, breaks=seq(0,20,by=5)), function(x) sum(x==0))

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `table()`: `table(cut(df$Sl, breaks=seq(0,20, by=5)), df$Value==0)`.

Answer (score 4):

Or using `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), using `cut` output as the grouping variable, we get the `sum` of 'Value' that are '0' (`!Value`).  By negating (`!`), the column will be converted to logical vector i.e. `TRUE` for 0 and `FALSE` all other values not equal to 0.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,sum(!Value) , .(gr=cut(Sl,breaks=seq(0,20, 5)))]
#        gr V1
#1:   (0,5]  1
#2:  (5,10]  2
#3: (10,15]  2
#4: (15,20]  1
```

Answer (score 3):

Your question used `table()`, but it lacked a second argument. It is needed to produce a contingency table. You can find the count of each bin with :

```
table(cut(df$Sl,4),df$Value)

             0 1 2 3 4 5 6
(0.981,5.75] 1 3 1 0 0 0 0
(5.75,10.5]  2 1 0 1 1 0 0
(10.5,15.2]  2 0 1 1 1 0 0
(15.2,20]    1 0 1 1 0 1 1
```

And the count of `Value == 0` for each bin :

```
table(cut(df$Sl,4),df$Value)[,"0"] 

(0.981,5.75]  (5.75,10.5]  (10.5,15.2]    (15.2,20] 
           1            2            2            1
```

Answer (score 1):

A more convoluted way using `sqldf` :

First we create a table defining the bins and ranges (min and max):

```
bins <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4), 
                   bins = c("(0,5]", "(5,10]", "(10,15]", "(15,20]"),
                   min = c(0, 6, 11, 16), 
                   max = c(5, 10, 15, 20))

   id    bins min max
1  1   (0,5]   0   5
2  2  (5,10]   6  10
3  3 (10,15]  11  15
4  4 (15,20]  16  20
```

Then we use the following query using both tables to bin each `sl` into its respective group using `BETWEEN` for those `Value` equal to 0.

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT bins, COUNT(Value) AS freq FROM df, bins
      WHERE (((sl) BETWEEN [min] AND [max]) AND Value = 0) 
      GROUP BY bins
      ORDER BY id")
```

Output:

```
     bins freq
1   (0,5]    1
2  (5,10]    2
3 (10,15]    2
4 (15,20]    1
```

Another alternative to simplify the construction of bins suggested by mts using `cut`, extracting the `levels` of the factor:

```
bins <- data.frame(id = 1:4, 
                   bins = levels(cut(Sl, breaks = seq(0, 20, 5))),
                   min = seq(1, 20, 5), 
                   max = seq(5, 20, 5))
```

Comment: Interesting solution, +1. Likely you could simplify the construction of `bins` with `cut` as used in the other answers, i.e. `cut(Sl,breaks=seq(0,20, 5))`?

Comment: @mts I edited it to include your suggestion. Thank you!