# Subsetting and counting values in columns in a data.frame

Tags: r, statistics

I have a data.frame with length 100000. Now I would like to count for different data.frame lengths(levels like 0.01 until 0.99) the positive and the negative values in this subset.

```
> dput(sumDF[1:100])
structure(c(3000, 2000, 5000, 4000, 1000, 4000, 0, 3000, 4000, 
2000, 2000, 3000, 1000, -3000, 2000, 0, 4000, 1000, 1000, 2000, 
2000, 2000, 2000, 1000, 3000, 1000, 4000, 3000, 2000, 3000, 1000, 
1000, 4000, 2000, 0, 1000, 2000, 5000, 3000, 3000, 0, 2000, 2000, 
3000, 1000, -1000, 2000, 1000, 2000, 3000, 2000, 3000, 2000, 
2000, 2000, 2000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 2000, 3000, 3000, 1000, 3000, 
1000, 2000, 1000, -1000, 0, 2000, 2000, 3000, 0, 3000, 2000, 
2000, 5000, 3000, 2000, 1000, 3000, 3000, 4000, 1000, 2000, 2000, 
3000, 0, 3000, 1000, 0, 4000, 4000, 2000, 3000, 0, 2000, 4000, 
0, 0), .Names = c("modelOutcome1", "modelOutcome2", "modelOutcome3", 
"modelOutcome4", "modelOutcome5", "modelOutcome6", "modelOutcome7", 
"modelOutcome8", "modelOutcome9", "modelOutcome10", "modelOutcome11", 
"modelOutcome12", "modelOutcome13", "modelOutcome14", "modelOutcome15", 
"modelOutcome16", "modelOutcome17", "modelOutcome18", "modelOutcome19", 
"modelOutcome20", "modelOutcome21", "modelOutcome22", "modelOutcome23", 
"modelOutcome24", "modelOutcome25", "modelOutcome26", "modelOutcome27", 
"modelOutcome28", "modelOutcome29", "modelOutcome30", "modelOutcome31", 
"modelOutcome32", "modelOutcome33", "modelOutcome34", "modelOutcome35", 
"modelOutcome36", "modelOutcome37", "modelOutcome38", "modelOutcome39", 
"modelOutcome40", "modelOutcome41", "modelOutcome42", "modelOutcome43", 
"modelOutcome44", "modelOutcome45", "modelOutcome46", "modelOutcome47", 
"modelOutcome48", "modelOutcome49", "modelOutcome50", "modelOutcome51", 
"modelOutcome52", "modelOutcome53", "modelOutcome54", "modelOutcome55", 
"modelOutcome56", "modelOutcome57", "modelOutcome58", "modelOutcome59", 
"modelOutcome60", "modelOutcome61", "modelOutcome62", "modelOutcome63", 
"modelOutcome64", "modelOutcome65", "modelOutcome66", "modelOutcome67", 
"modelOutcome68", "modelOutcome69", "modelOutcome70", "modelOutcome71", 
"modelOutcome72", "modelOutcome73", "modelOutcome74", "modelOutcome75", 
"modelOutcome76", "modelOutcome77", "modelOutcome78", "modelOutcome79", 
"modelOutcome80", "modelOutcome81", "modelOutcome82", "modelOutcome83", 
"modelOutcome84", "modelOutcome85", "modelOutcome86", "modelOutcome87", 
"modelOutcome88", "modelOutcome89", "modelOutcome90", "modelOutcome91", 
"modelOutcome92", "modelOutcome93", "modelOutcome94", "modelOutcome95", 
"modelOutcome96", "modelOutcome97", "modelOutcome98", "modelOutcome99", 
"modelOutcome100"))
> levels <- c(0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.95, 0.99)
> levelLength <- length(sumDF) * levels
> levelLength
 [1]  1000  5000 10000 20000 30000 40000 50000 60000 70000 80000 90000 95000 99000
```

My problem is that I get "how long the data.frame" should be, but I do not get the count of the "winners" and the "losers" in the data.frame.
Hence, the values of the 1 dimensional data.frame, which are greater than 0, winners, or smaller or equal then 0, losers.

To show this as an example, my data.frame has length `100000`. At the 1% level it's length is only `1000`. From this 1000 elements, as an example, are 800 above 0 and 200 below or equal to 0.
How to get the `800` and the `200`?

I tried the following:

```
countWin <- length(sumDF[1:levelLength > 0])
Warning message:
In 1:levelLength : numerical expression has 13 elements: only the first used
```

Any suggestions, how to get from my vectors only a certain count of elements?

I appreciate your replies.

**UPDATE**

Example:

My data.frame sumDF looks like that:

```
> sumDF[1:3]
modelOutcome1 modelOutcome2 modelOutcome3 
         3000          2000          5000
```

My data.frame sumDF has the length of `100000`

I want to subset my data.frame sumDF with the following level lengths.

```
> levelLength
 [1]  1000  5000 10000 20000 30000 40000 50000 60000 70000 80000 90000 95000 99000
```

So for levelLength 1000 I want to subset sumDF from 0 to 1000.

Furthermore, in this subset I want to count all vals `>0`, my winners and all which are `<=0`, my losers.

My final data.frame should look like that:

```
"levels" "winners" "losers"
0.01         900      100
0.05         2400     2600
0.10         6000     4000
0.20          .         .
0.30          .         .
0.40         
0.50         
0.60         
0.70         
0.80         
0.90         
0.95         
0.99
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking. Can you make a MINIMAL example please and provide expected output as well as phrase clearly in words what it is that you want? Besides that, I'm not sure, but have a look at my recent answer to this question that might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31981319/r-counting-the-number-of-a-specific-value-in-bins

Comment: I think you can use `length(subset(df,df < 0)` to get the count of elements below zero and use this likewise for other values you need...
You can add all our conditions to nested subset function and then use length function to get count of elements.

Comment: You have a vector, so `sum(sumDF<0)`.  If you have a matrix `colSums(sumDF<0)`

Comment: @mts Please see my update

Comment: @mrquad you should be able to deduce your final data.frame from the answers posted already...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dput` output is a `vector`.  To get the `sum` of values that are less than 0,

```
  sum(sumDF<0)
  #[1] 3
```

We can also use `table` to get the frequency of losers and winners

```
  table(sumDF <0)
  #FALSE  TRUE 
  # 97     3
```

If we have a `data.frame` or `matrix`

```
  colSums(sumDF <0)
```

Not sure I understand the recent edit, perhaps we get the frequency of 'sumDF' after `cut`ting the object into different bins.  Using `cut`, we can get those groups by specifying the `breaks`.

```
   levellength <-  c(1, 5, seq(10, 90, by=10), 95, 99)
   tbl <- table(cut(sumDF, breaks=levellength), sumDF)
```

Suppose, if we need to get the cumulative sum for each group, use `cumsum` after looping through the columns of 'tbl' with `apply`.

```
   tbl1 <- apply(tbl, 2, cumsum)
```

The labels (`rownames`) can be changed by using `sub` to match the numbers that follow the parentheses (`(`), and replace it with 1.

```
   rownames(tbl1) <- sub('(?<=\\()\\d+', '1', rownames(tbl1), perl=TRUE)
   tbl1
   #    sumDF
   #       -3000 -1000 0 1000 2000 3000 4000 5000
   #(1,5]      0     0 0    0    0    0    0    0
   #(1,10]     0     0 0    0    0    0    0    0
   #(1,20]     0     0 0    0    0    0    0    0
   #(1,30]     0     0 0    0    0    0    0    0
   #(1,40]     0     0 0    0    0    0    0    0
   #(1,50]     0     0 0    0    0    0    0    0
   #(1,60]     0     0 0    0    0    0    0    0
   #(1,70]     0     0 0    0    0    0    0    0
   #(1,80]     0     0 0    0    0    0    0    0
   #(1,90]     0     0 0    0    0    0    0    0
   #(1,95]     0     0 0    0    0    0    0    0
   #(1,99]     0     0 0    0    0    0    0    0
```

NOTE: The frequencies are all 0 based on the dput example.

We could also change the labels within the `cut` itself by making use of `labels` argument.  We create a custom label ('lvls') and use that in the `cut`. Other than that the code below is similar to above.

```
  lvls <- paste0('(', '1,', c(5,seq(10,90, by=10), 95, 99), ']')
  tbl <- table(sumDF, cut(sumDF, breaks=levellength, labels=lvls))
  apply(tbl, 1, cumsum)
```

Comment: Thx, for your reply! How can I subset the data.frame for different levels?

Comment: @mrquad Sorry, I didn't understand the `levels` in the expected output.  It is not found in the `dput` output

Comment: Thx for your reply! Is it possible to let each subset start at `0` so the subset is from `0-1000`, and from `0-5000` etc.

Comment: @mrquad I think we can do `cumsum` to get that frequency count

Comment: Sorry for the missunderstanding, in my example the data.frame is only 100 long so my level lengths are: `> levelLength
 [1]  1  5 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 95 99`

Comment: Would you be so kind to show an example using `cumsum`?

Comment: @mrquad We can loop through the columns of `tbl` and get the `cumsum`.  Based on the example data and the new levelength, the values are all 0.

Comment: Thx for your reply. My only problem is that the ranges go from `(1,5]`, `(5,10]` .... `(95,99]`. But I would like to have ranges like: `(1,5]`, `(1,10]` .... `(1,99]`. Any suggestion?

Comment: @mrquad We can replace the labels with `sub` or another option would be `labels` in the `cut` where we specify the custom labels